# Having trouble with waiting a child process with another child process in c++

Tags: c++, linux, process, child-process

I'm having trouble with controlling three child processes' output order in my c++ assignment.

So the requirement of the assignment is to create three child processes. A, B and C. Which I can accomplish it. Then I had to do some operations in three child processes.

A: 12 steps counter with print "A" and sleep for 1 second each time
B: Print "B" after two printed "A"s
C: print "C" after run B for 3 times

I have to keep processes running to accomplish the task...

```
sig_atomic_t sigusr1_count = 0;
bool bNeedDoWork = false;
bool cNeedDoWork = false;

void handlerForStep (int signal_number) //signal handler
{
 ++sigusr1_count;
}

void handlerForB (int signal_number) //signal handler
{
 bNeedDoWork = true;
}

void handlerForC (int signal_number) //signal handler
{
 cNeedDoWork = true;
}

int main() {
 using namespace std;
 pid_t childA_pid, childB_pid, childC_pid;

 /* Set up A handler operation*/
 struct sigaction sa; 
 memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa)); 
 sa.sa_handler = &handlerForStep; 
 sigaction (SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL); 

 childA_pid = fork();
 if (childA_pid == 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
     system("echo A");
     kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
     sleep(1);
   }
   exit(0);

 } else {
   childB_pid = fork();
   if (childB_pid == 0) {

     /*Set up B handler operation*/
     /*...*/

     //sleep until handler B receive signal
     while (true) {
       sleep(1);
       if (bNeedDoWork) {
         bNeedDoWork = false;
         system("echo B");
       }
     }
     exit(0);

   } else {
     childC_pid = fork();
     if (childC_pid == 0) {

       /*Set up C handler operation*/
       /*...*/

       //sleep until handler C receive signal
       while (true) {
         sleep(1);
         if (cNeedDoWork) {
           cNeedDoWork = false;
           system("echo C");
         }
       }
       exit(0);

     } else {
       while (true) {
         sleep(1);
         if (sigusr1_count != 0 && sigusr1_count % 2 == 0) {
           kill(childB_pid, SIGUSR1);
         }
         if (sigusr1_count != 0 && sigusr1_count % 6 == 0) {
           kill(childC_pid, SIGUSR1);
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

A bit lengthy. But I'm concerned about is this the really right way to generate processes.

I expected the result to be "A A B A A B A A B C A A B A A B A A B C"
But the result is "A A B A A C B ........"

Which the C printed before B printed. Even some of the letters A, B, C are messed up after this sequence.

Is this counting method to distinguish B process and C process:

```
if (sigusr1_count != 0 && sigusr1_count % 2 == 0) {
   kill(childB_pid, SIGUSR1);
}
if (sigusr1_count != 0 && sigusr1_count % 6 == 0) {
   kill(childC_pid, SIGUSR1);
}
```

correct?

Is it possible to use `wait(&status)` to prevent outputting C from operated before outputting B ?
Thankyou.

Comment: Your `B` and `C` processes need to sleep for longer than one second, don’t they?  In fact, shouldn’t they just `pause()` indefinitely?

Comment: I assume the signals are required for the assignment, but pipes would be much simpler and easier to make robust here.

Comment: But if B and C sleep longer, the output of A maybe printed three times or four times before the output of B and C as A output every 1 second

Comment: Any caught signal [interrupts `sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html)!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unable to understand the relation between signal and sleep. Can you explain further or even demonstrate some examples? Thanks a lot if you can! I'm pretty new to this topic.

Comment: A process executing `sleep(9999)` will return early if it catches a signal.  (The handler runs and then execution resumes after the `sleep`.)

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pause(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) to have the processes wait indefinitely on a signal.  It’s still possible to have a C be printed before its corresponding B, due to a race between those two processes; you’d have to communicate back from the B process to prevent that.  And `wait(2)` can’t help: only the A process *ever* exits (until, presumably, you use `^C` at the terminal to kill the whole process group).